# Automatic calculation of check number for ISBN-13

Tags: macros, calculations, number

Here is a simple example.
If I have the first 12 digits of ISBN-13 number.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} \parskip=12pt

\def\ISBNnumber{978-618-5645-08}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
            
If I have a 12-digit ISBN-13 number.
            
\ISBNnumber
            
For this ISBN number check number is 3.
            
Is there a way to automatically calculate this number and 
add it at the end so that I have a complete ISBN number 
with all 13 digits, such as this number below.
            
978-618-5645-08-3
 
\end{document}
```

How to make a new command that will calculate the check number, add it at the end so that we get a complete ISBN-13.
If anyone knows the answer to this question, please help and one example.

Comment: the calculation is quite simple and could be done in tex https://isbn-information.com/check-digit-for-the-13-digit-isbn.html  but when do you just get 12 digits of the isbn?

Comment: I know how to count a check number with pen and paper, but I don't know how to write a Latex code for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple weighted sum of the digits

https://isbn-information.com/check-digit-for-the-13-digit-isbn.html

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\isbncheck
\def\zz#1{#1-\zzz#1}

\def\zzz#1#2#3{\isbncheck=\numexpr#1+3*#2+#3\relax\zzzb}
\def\zzzb#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\advance\isbncheck\numexpr3*(#1+#3+#5+#7+#9)+#2+#4+#6+#8\relax\zzzc}
\def\zzzc{%
\isbncheck=\numexpr10-\isbncheck+10*(\isbncheck/10)\relax
\ifnum\isbncheck>9 \advance\isbncheck-10\relax\fi
\the\isbncheck
}
\begin{document}
        
If I have a 12-digit ISBN-13 number.
        

        
For this ISBN number check number is 3.
        
Is there a way to automatically calculate this number and 
add it at the end so that I have a complete ISBN number 
with all 13 digits, such as this number below.
 
\zz{978186197271}
      
978-618-5645-08-3

\zz{978618564508}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example you gave.
If the 12 digits are given in that way
\zz {978-618-5645-08}
where in addition to numbers in several places we have the sign -, calculating the check number becomes more complicated.

Is there a solution for this.

Comment: @ZeljkoHrcek I couldn't decide which input to use, if you always have the `-` it is easy just use `\def\zzz#1#2#3-`   and `\def\zzzb#1#2#3-#4#5#6#7-#8#9` with no other changes

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was very helpful and instructive for me